# Android Studio - Permission Denial, requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, sms

So, I have been scraping every single doc page and StackOverflow page to find an answer for this and I have literally found nothing. Today I have been making an app that needs to read all SMS's I receive and search for a specific phrase.

However, I realized I needed the RECEIVE_SMS permission, which I did - permission denied.

So I added the capability for the app to ask for permissions from the user, given the SDK is over 22 - permission denied.

I have plugged in every little thing I have found throughout these forums and nothing seems to be working, no matter what I do it still says permission denied and I can't read the SMS messages.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated because at the moment it's beginning to look like the app is a lost cause.

This is what the error looks like:

```
2019-10-30 14:50:53.097 1403-1413/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED flg=0x19000010 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{cb5e9afd0 1159:com.samsung.android.email.provider/u0a68} (pid=1159, uid=10068) requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender com.android.phone (uid 1001)
```

Here is the MainActivity file:

```
package app.genyie.tnat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestPermissions(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS);
    }

    private void requestPermissions(String permission, int requestCode) {
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Granting permission is necessary!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{permission},
                        requestCode);

                // requestCode is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECEIVE_SMS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.



                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.


                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.genyie.tnat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26"/>

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".BGServ"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If you need any other files let me know, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read SMS permission is officially taken off due to security concerns.
If you still need it, you would need to apply for whitelisting.

https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827

Comment: I was not aware of that, how would you go about whitelisting the app though? It is not an app I plan on putting on the Play Store or anything, it's just for my phone

Comment: You would need to do that while you upload the app to playstore. If you include the permission in your manifest, you would be prompted that your app has sensitive permissions and you would get a place to apply for justification. Meanwhile what is the purpose of accessing SMS? I could suggest some alternatives if you let me know the purpose.

Comment: yeah its just a project im making for myself, its not going on the playstore. It is an app that is always running in the background and is listening to my SMS texts and if it receives a certain phrase it will send an HTTP POST request with the latitude and longitude of the phone to a web server hosted my router - effectively its just my own take on a FindMyIphone-esque app. For it to work though, I need to be able to read the SMS messages. I'd be interested in any alternatives if you know any

Comment: In that case, you can send sms coupled with SMSRetriever API and it would solve your case. More details here https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: interesting, I'll try that out. Thank you!

Comment: If that helped you, consider accepting the answer :)